# Is it possible to import a video of somesort into Flash? If yes, how can I do that?

Tags: flash-cs6

For a game I'm developing, I'd like to add cutscenes. However, I figured I could save some time and code by simply playing cutscenes as videos instead of animating them. However, I'm not sure if it is possible to do so. I'd prefer my cutscene videos to be, like real game cutscenes, have no video playing controls like pausing etc. I'd also like them to take up the whole canvas.

I'm very new to flash so if you can answer, please explain very thoroughly.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

What you can try is the following:

1. Create a new frame by right-clicking on one of the blank boxes in the timeline of Flash (default at the bottom of the screen), and if it's not already selected, select it.
2. Drag-and-drop your video file onto the canvas (white space) in Flash. Make sure the video is in a directory that will be downloaded by people playing your game.
3. A popup will open:
   [image: Video import popup]
   Select "Load external video with playback component" and click Next.
4. The Skinning options will now appear. Under the "Skin" list, select "None" (right at the top)
   [image: Video import: Skinning]
5. Click Next and Finish.
6. Give your video an instance name (default is up at the top-right of the screen)
7. Do what you want with your video, move it around and resize etc.
8. If you don't want the video to auto-play:

   1. Click on the video
   2. Un-tick "autoPlay" in the Component Parameters area at the default right of the screen
9. When you want to play the video, use the code `(instancename).play()`. Stop it with `(instancename).stop()`, where `(instancename)` is what you typed in the Instance Name textbox. You can enter the code in by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>

Can't wait to see your game when it's finished!